# Post request for login API with jersey client

Tags: java, rest, jersey-client, api-authorization

I'm trying to run the below code to access the REST API, this REST API is secured with hawk authentication.
What i want to achieve here is with this POST request the server will return the AppTicket, this AppTicket will be used in subsequent API calls for testing.
But the problem is i'm getting the bad request error message.
I'm using jersey client with java.

```
    String payload= "{\"username\":\"test@domain.com\",\"password\":\"Password\",\"applnName\":\"my APP AngularJS\",\"applnType\":\"Web Application\",\"fingerprint\":\"1234314y31387ddhsks\",\"fpData\":\"fdata11\"}";
    Client restClient = Client.create();
    WebResource request = restClient.resource("https://test.server.com/api/login");
    ClientResponse response2 = request.type("application/json; charset=UTF-8").post(ClientResponse.class, payload);
    System.out.println(response2);
```

This is RAML based API, its RAML defition for POST call is as below,

Properties
username: required (string - minLength: 3 - maxLength: 100)
Valid email address provided by the organization

Example:

user@example.com
password: required (string)
Example:

s*ngPa55w*rd
fingerprint: (string)
A uniqe identifier for the device used to sign-in

fpData: (array of )
List of parameters used to compute fingerprint

applnType: required (one of Web Application, Android Application, iOS Application)
Type of application the user is logging in from

applnName: required (one of Web APP AngularJS, Mobile Android, Mobile NativeScript)

Can you please help me out to find the issues in this code here.

Comment: Could you please share the request format api call at Server level?

Comment: Updated with the API post call definition

Comment: Is there any error message in the response?

Comment: "returned a response status of 400 Bad Request" this is the error message